# Building/operating on an array inside LabView nested loop; not returning expected result

Tags: labview

I'm trying to create a simple VI that finds the smallest number that is a multiple of all numbers 1-N. The method I'm trying to implement is a while loop with a nested for loop. For each input number (let's call it M), the nested for loop iterates over the numbers 1-N and tests if the remainders of M/1, M/2, ..., M/N are zero or not. If a remainder is zero (i.e. my number M is divisible by this number), the code adds the number `1` to an array in the for loop. If it's not divisible, a `0` gets added to the array.

Then, outside the for loop, all the array elements are multiplied. If the product is `0` (which means at least one of the numbers 1-N was not a factor of M), then my while loop continues on to the next input number M. But if the product is not zero, the while loop stops and the indicator should show the number M (which is a multiple of the numbers 1-N).

I thought this was a pretty simple idea, but for some reason my code is not working correctly. For example, I tried an input of M=4 (indicted in the `divisible by numbers up to` slot), and expected an output of 6 in the `number` slot (since it's divisible by 1, 2, and 3). But the output just reads `1`. What am I doing wrong here? I've attached a picture of my block diagram, and I'm not sure how to upload my actual VI here, but I can do that too if requested and someone knows how. I'm new to LabView so any help is appreciated. Thank you!

[image: Block diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> then my while loop continues on to the next input number M

This is currently not the case. "Number" shows 1 every time it comes around because there is no code that changes it into anything else. I recommend using the [increment function](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/glang/increment/).

Also, when troubleshooting problems like this, I like to make an indicator for the loop counter to check if the loop is running as many times as it's supposed to.

EDIT:

Try this snippet. It increments your input every loop and also corrects the input to the "Quotient & Remainder" function (the loop counter is zero-indexed).

[image]

EDIT 2:

Finally, I'm still not sure if your method gives you the result you were looking for. In order to find what parts need attention, I recommend using [Highlight Execution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=WWsAU34PNug) & [probes](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361M-01/lvhowto/using_the_probe_tool/) (easiest to just right click a wire and select "probe").

Comment: You could get rid of the shift register on the While Loop by just wiring the [i] terminal to an Increment node and then wiring that to the For Loop and to the Number indicator.

Comment: @srm I don't know how I missed that. I've also realized the build array function there has no use.